# CSRF token missing or incorrect - displaying dynamic html content with django and js

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm trying to load data with ajax using [this](https://code-boxx.com/display-dynamic-content-html/) tutorial. I'm using Django as a framework for my project and unfortunately the data does not load propely, instead I get a following error message: "CSRF token missing or incorrect". I assume I need to somehow insert the csrf token into the request but not quite sure how to achieve this. Below is the code.

views.py

```
def ChapterListPL(request):
    chapter_pl = ChapterPL.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('issue')
    context = {
        'chapter_pl': chapter_pl,
        }
    return render(request, 'comics/chapters_pl.html', context)
```

html file

```
<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" value="AJAX Load" onclick="aload();"/>

<script>
    function aload() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'chapter_pl' %}");
        xhr.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.response;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the CSRF token in your HTML, read the token from the DOM with JavaScript and send on request through `X-CSRFToken` HTTP Header (as specified by the `CSRF_HEADER_NAME` setting):

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script>
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
</script>  



<div id="container"></div>
<input type="button" value="AJAX Load" onclick="aload();"/>

<script>
    function aload() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'chapter_pl' %}");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = this.response;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```

See the docs for using [AJAX with CSRF Tokens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax)

Answer (score 1):

All Django forms are CSRF protected by default, and your HTML input element counts as a form. Either include the {% csrf_token %} tag in your HTML or include the @csrf_exempt decorator in your views.py file. See more docs here:

[Django CSRF tokens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/)